# Needed: Cross platform C++ 2D graphics library for fast audio waveform presentation

Tags: c++, user-interface, 2d, cross-platform

I am trying to build a multimedia editor. It includes audio and relatively simple 2D graphics. I am using C++. I would like as much of it to be cross platform as possible.

I wrote audio interface classes for android and windows using a common API so I have that under control for now but I need a 2D graphics package and possibly a cross platform GUI as well.

The big challenge is in trying to render the time line. It needs to generate many rows of waveforms and intersperse them with characters and other shapes some of which may include blends and transparencies. Or rather I should say the big challenge has been animating the time line as often I will need to update it in real time. I have this working nicely using a lot of cashing and shifting around of the pixels of off-screen bitmaps. If I have 50 lines on the screen and the screen is 1000 pixels wide that translates to over 50,000 line draw operations per frame. Actually I use multi segment lines that end up drawing 3 times as many segments. To generate each line of the audio waveform it needs to look at a few hundred samples of audio and compute the max and min values or maybe do an FFT to create a line of different colored pixels if I want to offer this to the user some day. Various forms of cashing let me do this with reasonable latency.

The animation side of things will include everything from moving poly lines and polygons around in 2D to importing images and playing back moving multiple images (video) at different arbitrary frame rates. I don’t think 3D is very useful for now anyway.

At the moment I am using a crazy mix of GDI and GDI plus on windows and running it all in a win32 “thing”.  This is not great as I cannot invert regions in off screen bitmaps and I cannot draw individual pixels quickly enough to for instance show a spectrogram in real time. I think they were written in the 90s so there must be something newer I can use and get better performance and cross platform capabilities. I have been pulling out my remaining hair to figure out what to use.
I found another library on android that will let me set pixels and the performance actually seems a lot better but it does not support writing text. So I am hoping there is something else I could use for that.  On Android the plan is to generate the bitmap and then blit it into an interface build with a Native Android GUI.  These solutions do not seem great though a vast majority of the rest of the code can be ported without issue just being standard C++ and these horrors being cleanly wrapped.

I have seen a few potential candidates: openGL and Vulkan, seem to do 2D graphics as well as 3D but perhaps they are much more complex then what I need.
For the GUI I looked at QT but gave up on it (it seems to need half of my hard drive and has an incomprehensible licensing model). I recently started looking at IMGUI. They say it redraws on every frame. I don’t know how that will play with my existing rendering system and if it would drain a phones battery. A while ago I was able to get visual studio to create a cross platform App that would run on android but for some reason ditched that perhaps I should revisit it.

For the time line I need to draw a waveform. This could be done by drawing a lot of lines (50-150 k/frame) they can just be vertical ones for the most part, they do not need to be of fractional pixel width they need not be anti-aliased, and can have their end points specified with just integers. I also need to add some other lines polygons and text that does need to be anti-aliased. I may need to set a lot of pixels directly. Blends and transparencies would be nice but not essential. I also need to copy square chunks of bit map around. I also need sprites for things like the cursor. I am currently doing this by copying fragments of the bit map on and off screen. It would also be very nice to be able to select square regions of off screen bitmaps to invert for doing selections. And I need to assemble this off screen in a 2 or 3 buffer configuration so I can reuse chunks of one bitmap to make the next one and present it to the user in a real time animation. (all of this works with my GDI / GDI + wrapper though I have to work around the inversion problem)

For the animation part I need to draw similar graphics primitives, though it would also be nice to draw characters at arbitrary angles and scaling. As for Video if I can extract the images I guess I could blit them to the screen as needed. Maybe I would need yet another package to composite them into the other parts of the frame. Farther it would be nice to be able to write the animation out in a higher quality format in non real time to make a video file of some kind. It would be nice if I did not have to wrap yet another framework to make this happen though I can deal with this if I need to.

For the GUI it does not have to be all that fancy. Ideally I would like to have 2 or 3 floating and dockable windows on the PC and a few screens on a phone. I will have to make slightly different UIs for both but the time line bitmap and the media window bitmaps should be reusable for the most part. I just need standard widgets for the most part though.

My needs are somewhere in-between that of a game and that of a regular boring old forms app except for the need to animate the waveform.

Does anyone have any suggestions and perhaps know these systems well enough to know if they have a good chance to do what I need?

I fear I would have to spend weeks learning each one just to see if they give me the capabilities I need.

Is IMGUI likely to eat the phones battery just to make the cursor blink?

Any tips would be most welcome.

Comment: It seems it's time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Late to the party, but if anyone else lands here: perhaps https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ could offer some better chances. BTW, @Andre, what did you end up using eventually?